# Problema al acceder a un UserControl por su nombre

Tags: vb.net, windows-forms, excepciones, cast, usercontrol

he creado un  usercontrol llamado controlN al que estoy intentando acceder por su nombre, el control contiene un textbox llamado "TextBox1", el control en ml form se llama "Controln1"

```
Dim MC As controlN = DirectCast(Controls("Controln1"), controlN)
MC.TextBox1.Text = "Texto"
```

pero me arroja el error null reference exception en la segunda línea porque en MC me regresa el valor/objeto "Nothing".
Necesito acceder al control por su nombre por que lo creo dinámicamente.
Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Controls es la coleccion de controles del formulario? y si mejor guardas en un array los controles que vas creando?

Comment: No es mucho más complicado de lo que lo quiero hacer? Yo solo uso o tengo pensado usar esas dos líneas

Comment: En general, no.. Te ahorras un loop enorme (en toda la coleccion de controles)... ademas ya lo tenes ahi, a mano, siempre que lo necesites.. y como lo creaste en tiempo de ejecucion, lo guardaste vos... ademas, depende donde hayas guardado el control, tendrias que buscarlo en las ramas de los hijos... no.. suele ser una mejor opcion en general... pero... si MC devulve nothing, es porque no esta encontrando un control con ese nombre.. podra estar dentro de otro control y por eso?

Comment: Además, si guardo controles complejos con imágenes, no se vuelve muy pesado para la memoria? Yo no he usado arreglos de controles

Comment: Si efectivamente esta dentro de un tabcontrol

Comment: No estas guardando el control.. estas guardando una referencia al control... solo es una variable que apunta al control, como cualquier otra variable. De igual forma, si esta dentro de un tab.. primero deberias ubicar el tab, y luego buscar en su coleccion de controls el control que vos queres...

Comment: Si Metes un Textbox Dentro de Tu UserControl y Usas el UserControl Agregando-lo al Formulario, as de Crear-le los Métodos Necesarios Para Acceder a sus Controles ( Textbox.Text ) Ya Que Son Necesarias para Acceder a su Contenido. 
En el UserControl as de Crear-le una Propiedad o Función GetText Para Acceder al Texto de TextBox Ya Que Se Alojan en Dominios de Aplicación Distintos Donde Cada Control Tiene Su Dominio de Aplicación ( Los UserControls Son Cómo Una Aplicación Aparte del Aplicativo Que Los Usa ) Por esto no puedes llamar al Textbox Aunque lo Hayas Puesto en Tu Control de Usuario